# How can I check what version of mapnik I am using in python?

Tags: python, mapnik

I am using Python 3.5 and the mapnik library bindings available through the [python-mapnik](https://github.com/mapnik/python-mapnik) project.  I have multiple versions of the mapnik library on my machine, how can I do a sanity check to see which version of mapnik the is being used by the python bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way but the package in question has a module `paths` which can be inspected to reveal what is being bound:

```
import mapnik
print(mapnik.paths.__all__)
```

Example output:

```
['/usr/lib/mapnik/3.0', '/usr/lib/mapnik/3.0/input', '/usr/share/fonts']
```